# How to continiously read data from a NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

So I'm currently learning about networking between a client and a server and I decided to try to write my own client and server.

I implemented a way of receiving data and it goes as follows..

The server expects a packet that is structured like this.. `[ packetSize(2bytes), [data] ]`, so the first two bytes is the entire packet size `(size(2bytes) + data(X bytes))`.

And my implementation receives all the data just fine, I just feel like it could be cleaner, by maybe using a `BinaryReader` or something similar, the goal here is to maybe get rid of all the `Buffer.BlockCopy(..` or anything to make it cleaner, maybe even improving it.

```
class Connection
{
    private TcpClient _socket;

    private int _received;
    private int _packetSize = -1;
    private int bufferSize = 1024;
    private int offset = 0;
    private byte[] _buffer;
    private byte[] _packet;


    private BinaryReader reader;

    public Connection(TcpClient client)
    {
        _buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        _socket = client;
        reader = new BinaryReader(_socket.GetStream());

        Console.WriteLine($"Client connected: {_socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
        ProcessPackets();
    }

    public void ProcessPackets()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            /* 
             * Packet Initializer
             * Receive The PacketSize
             * Instantiate the Packet byte[], giving it the correct size
             */

            _received = _socket.Client.Receive(_buffer, 0, 2, SocketFlags.None);
            _packetSize = BitConverter.ToInt16(_buffer, 0);
            _packet = new byte[_packetSize];

            /* Copy over the bytes that represent the size and update the offset. */
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, _packet, 0, _received);
            offset = _received;

            /* Append data to the packet while there still is data to receive. */
            while (_received < _packetSize)
            {
                var delta = _packetSize - _received;
                if (delta <= bufferSize)
                {
                    _received += _socket.Client.Receive(_buffer, 0, delta, SocketFlags.None);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, _packet, offset, _received - offset);
                }
                else
                {
                    _received += _socket.Client.Receive(_buffer, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, _packet, offset, _received - offset);
                }

                offset += bufferSize;
            }

            //Reset the offset.
            offset = 0;

            /*junk*/
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_packet.Skip(2).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"Data received: {data}");

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `_socket`? Could you provide more code?

Comment: @aepot there we go :-)

Comment: Did I answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

*Future note: avoid making Code Review request for not finished yet solution.*

Few notes:

- What I'm really missing here: [Asynchronous programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)
- There's no reason to stay in ASCII, use UTF8 instead. Also ASCII is subset of UTF-8.
- You run receiving packet once and then nothing.
- You aren't return data anywhere, why?
- `Buffer.BlockCopy` is really fast but reading data from network directly to target array would look more efficient.
- Avoid making fields (global variables) for single method. Make locals instead. If you think that declaring primitives e.g. `int` field once is more efficient than creating it once per loop iteration as local variable, then you're wrong.
- Int16 is signed type. You can double the packet max size just changing it to UInt16.
- There's no sense to store the data length in the received output data because `array.Length` will contain it.

Here's my try to play with.

```cs
class Connection
{
    private readonly TcpClient _client;
    private readonly NetworkStream _stream;
    private readonly Task _task;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    private const int bufferSize = ushort.MaxValue; // 65536

    public Connection(TcpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = ReceiveAsync(_cts.Token);

        Console.WriteLine($"Client connected: {_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string message)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        ushort size = (ushort)data.Length;
        await _stream.WriteAsync(BitConverter.GetBytes(size)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _stream.WriteAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, 2), token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                int size = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
                int offset = 0;

                // normally there will be only one iteration of this loop but
                // ReadAsync doesn't guarantee that 'received' will always match
                // requested bytes amount
                while (offset < size) 
                {
                    int received = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(offset, size - offset), token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (received == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Client {_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint} disconnected.");
                        return;
                    }
                    offset += received;
                }

                // probably firing an event here would be helpful
                // byte[] output = buffer.AsSpan(0, size).ToArray();
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.AsSpan(0, size));
                Console.WriteLine($"Data received: {data}");
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            if (_client.Connected)
            {
                _stream.Close();
                Console.WriteLine($"Connection to {_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint} closed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Test the class a lot with closing the connection on both sides
            // I'm not sure how it will behave because I didn't test it
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _task.Wait();
    }
}
```